# Transform any null input to empty string

Tags: php, mysql

So I've got a while loop, inside I have `$array_collections` that gives me 35 value per loop, I want to verify for every value if it's equal to `NULL` then give it an empty string. I did that :

```
while ($array_collections = tep_db_fetch_array($query)) { 

    foreach ($array_collections as $key => $value) {
        if (is_null($value)) {
             $array_collections[$key] = "";
        }
    }

    $docs[] = new \Elastica\Document('', \Glam\HttpUtils::jsonEncode(
        array(
            'X' => $array_collections['X'],
            ... etc
    )));
}
```

This technically should work, but the loop goes over 500K elements so it's huge, and for every element we put it into a table, problem is that I run out of memory at some point. So is there another simple way to give any given `NULL` value an empty string without looping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_map` function to replace null values into empty string.

```
  $array_collections=array_map(function($ar)
  {
    if(isset($ar) && $ar!=null){
      return $ar;
    }
    return '';
  },$array_collections);
```

Above code replace all null values to empty string. No need of loop.

Comment: So many replies that answers my problem differently, thanks !

Comment: This answer is misleading and potentially wrong.  The loose comparison on `null` will also be satisfied by any "falsey" value (like `0`, `'0'`, an empty string, and more).  `isset()` already checks that a variable exists and is not null.

Answer (score 1):

well, you can put NOT NULL constraint with empty string as DEFAULT value in the DB for that so you dont need to do that in php using looping, but if you dont want to change the DB design then you can use COALESCE in your query

```
select COALESCE(yourfield,'') from table
```

it will convert NULL value into empty string

Comment: Thanks! But what is less hungry, to do this, or use `array_map` ? But I didn't know about COALESCE(), I learnt something today.

Answer (score 0):

you can use array_walk:

```
function replace_null(&$lsValue, $key) {
     if(is_null($lsValue)) {
         $lsValue = "";
     }
}

array_walk($array_collections, 'replace_null');
```